# Search function is not searching on every page of pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css

The search box that I have added to my HTML table is only working on the current page of the table and not on the other paginated pages of the table. I want it to show the search result from anywhere in the entire table, and it should have the same pagination limit as table pagination.

And I also want to show the current page row count and total page row count at the bottom of my table in this format, which keeps changing as per the table rows, e.g., "Showing 1 to 2 of 8,"  and it should work on the search page too. You can see it at the bottom of the page. It will be really helpful if the expert helps me out with this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, pagination;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  table = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    isFound = false;
    for (j = 0; j < alltags.length; j++) {
      td = alltags[j];
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          j = alltags.length;
          isFound = true;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}


//Table Search Script Ends

// Table Pagination Script Starts 
const paginationNumbers = document.getElementById("pagination-numbers");
const pageCount_ele = document.getElementById("pageCount") // Handle the page values
const currentPage_ele = document.getElementById("currentPage")
const paginatedList = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
const listItems = paginatedList.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");

const paginationLimit = 2;
const pageCount = Math.ceil(listItems.length / paginationLimit);
let currentPage = 1;

const disableButton = (button) => {
  button.classList.add("disabled");
  button.disable = true;
};

const enableButton = (button) => {
  button.classList.remove("disabled");
  button.disable = false;
};

const handlePageButtonsStatus = () => {
  if (currentPage === 1) {
    disableButton(prevButton);
  } else {
    enableButton(prevButton);
  }

  if (pageCount === currentPage) {
    disableButton(nextButton);
  } else {
    enableButton(nextButton);
  }
};

const handleActivePageNumber = () => {

  currentPage_ele.innerText = currentPage

  enableButton(prevButton) // Assing them as clickable
  enableButton(nextButton)

  if (currentPage == pageCount) {
    disableButton(nextButton) // if last page disable next

  }
  if (currentPage == 1) {
    disableButton(prevButton) // if 1st disable prev
  }
};

const appendPageNumber = (index) => {
  const pageNumber = document.createElement("button");
  pageNumber.className = "pagination-number";
  pageNumber.innerHTML = index;
  pageNumber.setAttribute("page-index", index);
  pageNumber.setAttribute("aria-label", "Page " + index);

  paginationNumbers.appendChild(pageNumber);
};

const getPaginationNumbers = () => {

};

const setCurrentPage = (pageNum) => {
  currentPage = pageNum;

  handleActivePageNumber();
  handlePageButtonsStatus();

  const prevRange = (pageNum - 1) * paginationLimit;
  const currRange = pageNum * paginationLimit;

  listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.classList.add("hidden");
    if (index >= prevRange && index < currRange) {
      item.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
};

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  getPaginationNumbers();
  setCurrentPage(1);

  prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
  });

  nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  });
  pageCount_ele.innerText = pageCount
});
```

```css
.result {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.canel-trains-grids {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.canel-trains-grids .left-cancel {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.canel-trains-grids .left-cancel span {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #34A853;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: auto;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel label {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 39px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input {
  width: 230px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
  float: right;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* Responsive Table Start */

.rstable {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 16px 0px;
}

.rstable table {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.rstable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.rstable tr td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 9px;
  color: #333;
}

.rstable th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 9px;
  background: #004287;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.rstable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f9fbfdc4;
}

.rstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #dae9f3;
}

.rstable tr td a {
  color: #004287;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  .rstable table {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .rstable table {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .rstable thead {
    display: none;
  }
  .rstable td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 90%;
  }
  .rstable td {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 26%;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #333;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .rstable td:before {
    content: attr(data-title);
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
  .rstable td {
    width: 23%;
  }
}


/* Responsive Table Ends */

.arrow-right,
.arrow-left {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.arrow-right {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.arrow-left {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.pagination-container {
  width: calc(100% - 0rem);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0rem 0;
  justify-content: right;
  /* text-align: center; */
}

.pagination-number,
.pagination-button {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #0085b6;
  ;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.newpagination-numbers {
  font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #333;
  ;
  border: none;
  margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.newpagination-numbers:hover {
  background: #34A853;
}

.pagination-number:hover,
.pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background: #FBBC05;
}

button.disabled {
  background-color: #c82333;
  /*Make it whatever color you want*/
}

.disabled {
  color: #333 !important;
  pointer-events: none !important;
  cursor: not-allowed !important;
}

span.disabled {
  border-color: #333 !important;
}

.pagination-number.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0085b6;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <div class='canel-trains-grids'>
    <div class='left-cancel'><span>22 Tech Company Listed</span>
    </div>
    <div class='right-cancel'>
      <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder='Enter Train Number'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Result Table Starts -->
<div class="rstable">
  <table id="paginated-list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Extn.</th>
        <th>Joined</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Engine</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Airi Satou</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Accountant</td>
        <td data-title="Office">No1</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">1</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar1</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">01</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Germany</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome1</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">97</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td data-title="Position">CEO</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">2</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar2</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">02</td>
        <td data-title="Country">India</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome2</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">96</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Ashton Cox</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Technical Author</td>
        <td data-title="Office">Software Engineer</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">3</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar3</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">03</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Japan</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome3</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">95</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Bradley Greer</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Integration Specialist</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">4</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar4</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">04</td>
        <td data-title="Country">UK</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome4</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">94</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Software Engineer</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">5</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">05</td>
        <td data-title="Country">USA</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome5</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">93</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">6</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">06</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Canada</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome6</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">92</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Bruno Nash</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Sales Assistant</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">7</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">07</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Italy</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome7</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">91 </td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Caesar Vance</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Javascript Developer</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">8</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">08</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Mexico</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome8</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">90</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="width: 100%; display: flex;align-items: center;">
  <div style="text-align: left; width: 50%;">
    <span id="currpagecount">Showing 1 to 2 of </span><span id="totalrowscount">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-container">
    <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-button" aria-label="Previous page" title="Previous page">
            <span class="arrow-left"></span>
        </button>
    <div id="pagination-numbers" class="newpagination-numbers">
      <span id="currentPage"></span>/<span id="pageCount"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="pagination-button" id="next-button" aria-label="Next page" title="Next page">
            <span class="arrow-right"></span>
        </button>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- Result Table Ends -->
```

Comment: Why do you use HTML comments `<!-- -->` inside JavaScript code?

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, I just added it to segregate the script.

Comment: The filter function in textfield and pagination is different, so one of them is working, but not both, you should filter the result from actual data, not in pagination result and maybe you use ```.includes()``` rather than ```indexOf()``` as when you are on the other page from pagination, searching maybe not work well as it looks for index that is not present on that page(ex: page 2, searching index 0), you can achieve it, but different approach, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Table Search Script Ends

// Table Pagination Script Starts 

const paginationNumbers = document.getElementById("pagination-numbers");
const pageCount_ele = document.getElementById("pageCount") // Handle the page values
const currentPage_ele = document.getElementById("currentPage")
const paginatedList = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
const listItems = paginatedList.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");
const currentSearchOfTotal = document.getElementById('currpagecount')
const totalRowsCount = document.getElementById('totalrowscount')
const paginationLimit = 2;
const searchPaginationLimit = 2
const pageCount = Math.ceil(listItems.length / paginationLimit);
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
let currentPage = 1;
let searching = false


let searchArray=[]
let searchPageCount
function myFunction() {
  searching = true
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, pagination;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  table = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  searchArray=[]
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    isFound = false;
      for (j = 0; j < alltags.length; j++) {
        td = alltags[j];
          if (td) {
              txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
              if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                  tr[i].style.display = "";
                  j = alltags.length;
                  isFound = true;
              }
        }
    }
    if(isFound){searchArray.push(tr[i])}
      if (!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  setCurrentSearchPage(1)
  pageCount_ele.innerText = Math.ceil(searchArray.length/searchPaginationLimit)
}

const disableButton = (button) => {
  button.classList.add("disabled");
  button.disable = true;
};

const enableButton = (button) => {
  button.classList.remove("disabled");
  button.disable = false;
};

const handlePageButtonsStatus = () => {
  if (currentPage === 1) {
  disableButton(prevButton);
} else {
  enableButton(prevButton);
}

if (pageCount === currentPage) {
  disableButton(nextButton);
} else {
  enableButton(nextButton);
}
};

const handleSearchPageButtonsStatus = () => {
if (currentPage === 1) {
  disableButton(prevButton);
} else {
  enableButton(prevButton);
}

if (Math.ceil(searchArray.length/searchPaginationLimit || searchArray.length==0) === currentPage) {
  disableButton(nextButton);
} else {
  enableButton(nextButton);
}
};

const handleActivePageNumber = () => {

  currentPage_ele.innerText = currentPage

  enableButton(prevButton) // Assing them as clickable
  enableButton(nextButton)

  if (currentPage == pageCount){
    disableButton(nextButton) // if last page disable next
  }
  if (currentPage == 1){
    disableButton(prevButton) // if 1st disable prev
  }
};

const handleSearchActivePageNumber = () => {

  currentPage_ele.innerText = currentPage

  enableButton(prevButton) // Assing them as clickable
  enableButton(nextButton)
  console.log(Math.ceil(searchArray.length/searchPaginationLimit))
  if (currentPage == (Math.ceil(searchArray.length/searchPaginationLimit))){
    disableButton(nextButton) // if last page disable next
  }
  if (currentPage == 1){
    disableButton(prevButton) // if 1st disable prev
  }
};

const setCurrentPage = (pageNum) => {
  currentPage = pageNum;

  handleActivePageNumber();
  handlePageButtonsStatus();

  const prevRange = (pageNum - 1) * paginationLimit;
  const currRange = pageNum * paginationLimit;
  currentSearchOfTotal.innerHTML=`Showing ${currRange-1} to ${currRange} of `
  totalRowsCount.innerHTML = `${listItems.length}`

  listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.classList.add("hidden");
    if (index >= prevRange && index < currRange) {
      item.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
};

const setCurrentSearchPage = (pageNum) => {
  currentPage = pageNum;

  handleSearchActivePageNumber();
  handleSearchPageButtonsStatus();

  const prevRange = (pageNum - 1) * searchPaginationLimit;
  const currRange = pageNum * searchPaginationLimit;
  currentSearchOfTotal.innerHTML=`Showing search results ${currRange-1} to ${searchArray.length>1 ? currRange : 1} of `
  totalRowsCount.innerHTML = `${searchArray.length}`
  searchArray.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.classList.add("hidden");
    if (index >= prevRange && index < currRange) {
      item.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
};

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  setCurrentPage(1);
  prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(!searching){
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1)
      pageCount_ele.innerText = pageCount
    }
    else if(searching){
      setCurrentSearchPage(currentPage-1)
      pageCount_ele.innerText = Math.ceil(searchArray.length/searchPaginationLimit)
    }
  });

  nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(!searching){
      setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
      pageCount_ele.innerText = pageCount
    }
    else{
      setCurrentSearchPage(currentPage+1)
      pageCount_ele.innerText = Math.ceil(searchArray.length/searchPaginationLimit)
    };
  });
  pageCount_ele.innerText = pageCount
});
```

```css
.result {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

  .canel-trains-grids {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.canel-trains-grids .left-cancel {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.canel-trains-grids .left-cancel span {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #34A853;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    width: auto;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel label {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 39px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input {
    width: 230px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
    float: right;
}

.canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input:focus {
    outline: none;
}


/* Responsive Table Start */

.rstable {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 16px 0px;
}

.rstable table {
    font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.rstable tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.rstable tr td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 9px;
    color: #333;
}

.rstable th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px 9px;
    background: #004287;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.rstable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f9fbfdc4;
}

.rstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #dae9f3;
}

.rstable tr td a {
    color: #004287;
    font-size: 16px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .rstable table {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .rstable table {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .rstable thead {
        display: none;
    }
    .rstable td:first-child {
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-grid;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .rstable td {
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-grid;
        width: 26%;
        vertical-align: top;
        color: #333;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .rstable td:before {
        content: attr(data-title);
        font-weight: 500;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
    .rstable td {
        width: 23%;
    }
}
/* Responsive Table Ends */      
.arrow-right,
    .arrow-left {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px auto;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-top: 2px solid #000;
        border-left: 2px solid #000;
    }
    
    .arrow-right {
        transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    
    .arrow-left {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    
.pagination-container {
    width: calc(100% - 0rem);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0rem 0;
    justify-content: right;
    /* text-align: center; */
}

.pagination-number,
.pagination-button {
    font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #0085b6;;
    border: none;
    margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.newpagination-numbers {
    font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #333;;
    border: none;
    margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 2rem;
    line-height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.newpagination-numbers:hover {
background: #34A853;
}
.pagination-number:hover,
.pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    background: #FBBC05;
}

button.disabled {
background-color: #c82333; /*Make it whatever color you want*/
}


.disabled { 
    
    color: #333 !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
    cursor: not-allowed !important;
    
}

span.disabled {
    border-color: #333 !important;

}


.pagination-number.active {
    color: #fff;
    background: #0085b6;
}
```

```html
  <div class="result">
    <div class='canel-trains-grids'>
        <div class='left-cancel'>
          <span>22 Rajdhani Express Trains Listed</span>
        </div>
        <div class='right-cancel'>
            <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder='Enter Train Number'>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Result Table Starts -->
<div class="rstable">
  <table id="paginated-list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>Joined</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Browser</th>
      <th>Platform</th>
      <th>Engine</th>
      <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Airi Satou</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Accountant</td>
        <td data-title="Office">No1</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">1</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar1</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">01</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Germany</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome1</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">97</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td data-title="Position">CEO</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">2</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar2</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">02</td>
        <td data-title="Country">India</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome2</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">96</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Ashton Cox</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Technical Author</td>
        <td data-title="Office">Software Engineer</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">3</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar3</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">03</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Japan</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome3</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">95</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Bradley Greer</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Integration Specialist</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">4</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar4</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">04</td>
        <td data-title="Country">UK</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome4</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">94</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Software Engineer</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">5</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">05</td>
        <td data-title="Country">USA</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome5</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">93</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">6</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">06</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Canada</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome6</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">92</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Bruno Nash</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Sales Assistant</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">7</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">07</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Italy</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome7</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">91 </td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td data-title="Name">Caesar Vance</td>
        <td data-title="Position">Javascript Developer</td>
        <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
        <td data-title="Extn.">8</td>
        <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
        <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
        <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
        <td data-title="Contact">08</td>
        <td data-title="Country">Mexico</td>
        <td data-title="Browser">Chrome8</td>
        <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
        <td data-title="Engine">90</td>
        <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="width: 100%; display: flex;align-items: center;">
  <div style="text-align: left; width: 50%;">
      <span id="currpagecount">Showing 1 to 2 of </span><span id="totalrowscount">8</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pagination-container">
    <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-button" aria-label="Previous page" title="Previous page">
      <span class="arrow-left"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="pagination-numbers" class="newpagination-numbers">
      <span id="currentPage"></span>/<span id="pageCount"></span>
    </div>
    <button class="pagination-button" id="next-button" aria-label="Next page" title="Next page">
      <span class="arrow-right"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working final version. Hope you like it

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I will accept and upvote this answer. The search problem is solved. But when searching this keyword, "Island Trading," it shows all 8 results on the same page. What if the result is more? We need to set the limit at 4 or 5, or whatever we want. When searching for this keyword, click on the pagination left arrow to see if this behavior is alright or not.

Comment: I have also mentioned one more thing you forgot to solve, which I mentioned above, and here it is. I also want to show the current page row count and total page row count at the bottom of my table in this format, which keeps changing as per the table rows, e.g., "Showing 1 to 2 of 8." You can see it at the bottom of the page. It will be really helpful if you help me out with this.

Comment: Hi again my Friend. You added this in this new question  as I have not seen it in the previous one. No worry will do it either today later on or tomorow same Time.Will be editing m'y answer.

Comment: Sure, I will wait for your answer. I mean to say, the pagination limit should work on search too. When you search "Br," you will get 4 results on the same page, and when you click on the Next arrow, you will get 1 result, then 2, then 1. Is this behavior correct? Read the above comment too.

Comment: @KasRoudra Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The search function seems to be fine, but it seems that the items that are displayed should be also properly factored in. Currently you only hide the items that you haven't found in the search function, while the remaining items that actually match your search criteria has the hidden class applied which needs to be removed so that they are displayed.

As far as pagination is concerned, the logic is scattered out a lot. I would suggest encapsulating the logic to a function that calculates the current page index, the total number of items in the table and sets the appropriate text content of pagination string text or the just the values in it. Then using this function on document load and while triggering the search function (and anything that potentially modifies how the table is displayed) should keep everything in sync.

Comment: Please suggest me what to do and where in the code. If please do it and post it here.

Comment: Hi Shoeb I am going to post a possible solution to your needs hopefuly in a minute pls check.

Comment: Hi Shoeb added the row counts and also made kind of a quick fix (not the one I like) 'when changing page while on searching' a simple way is a refresh page and starting from begining. You can look for a better solution with some code. Enjoy Coding!

Comment: @Mehdi When searching this keyword, "Island Trading," it shows all 8 results on the same page. It should have the same pagination limit as paging, which is currently 2. The count, which we are showing at the bottom, is not working properly. When you search the above-mentioned keyword, you will see a count of 1-2 of 8, which is wrong as you are showing 8. After getting the search result, when you click on the arrow, it refreshes and starts from the beginning, but it shouldn't start from the beginning; it should go after that and shouldn't show the message when clicking on the arrow.

Comment: @Mehdi I was waiting for your reply, you didn't replied.

Comment: Ok Shoeb will give it another try but you did not upvote last time. I will try to post a solution in 30min

Comment: you also asked first to show all results in one page and now with pagination

Comment: This final one is working nicely with search pagination (showing search pages and search items) at any page and with nice filter. You can test by running snippet and then full page  (not to see the console)

Comment: I expect an upvote and and answer accepted and feel free to ask for other help  if I can help of course

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you so much; almost every issue is resolved. I just want to know what the pagination behavior should be on the normal result page and the search result page if the search result is zero. I think both the left and right arrows should be disabled for clicking; the count should be 1-1. What do you say?

Comment: @Mehdi Share your email address so I can contact you for web development purposes.

Comment: @Shoeb I am glad that you like it and will be happy to help more. You are right when search result is 0 the left count should be 0 to 0 of 0 and the right 1/1 will be fixed hopefuly today. Actualy I am not really a development specialist (not even a computer scientist , but just love that since my younger age) there are here in SO much much better than I am. But if there could be any business opportunity in Web dev or AI I am ready to have a closer look . Here is my email pharmakidsarl@gmail.com. You can still post in SO and I will be as usual more than happy with others here to help

Comment: @Mehdi The best thing about you is that you are not leaving what you have started. You are trying to find the solution, even though it's challenging for you. That's the best, and I hope you have a great future ahead. Always be like this, and I guarantee that you will go beyond your imagination.

Comment: @Mehdi Fix the search result pagination and count behavior as well; if the pagination table has no result, then it should also show the same behavior.

Comment: @Mehdi I have edited your answer, set the pagination limit to 15, and added 8 more rows to the HTML. It should be like 1 to 15 of 11 entries and 16 to 16 of 11 entries (correct me if I am wrong about the last entry). I don't know whether my edited version will get approved or not.

Comment: @Mehdi What if the result table has a lower row count than the pagination limit?

Comment: @Mehdi I have been waiting for your reply since yesterday, but you haven't replied.